# How do I find the edges of a vertex using igraph and R?

Tags: r, igraph

Say I have this example graph, i want to find the edges connected to vertex 'a'

```
 d <- data.frame(p1=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'),
                 p2=c('b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'e', 'e'))

library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(d, directed=FALSE)
print(g, e=TRUE, v=TRUE)
```

I can easily find a vertex:

```
 V(g)[V(g)$name == 'a' ]
```

But i need to reference all the edges connected to the vertex 'a'.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See the documentation on [igraph iterators](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/igraphbook/igraphbook-iterators.html); in particular the from() and to() functions.

In your example, "a" is V(g)[0], so to find all edges connected to "a":

```
E(g) [ from(0) ]
```

Result:

```
[0] b -- a
[1] c -- a
[2] d -- a
```

Comment: Note to Python-igraph users: Equivalent to this solution is to use EdgeSeq's [select](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.EdgeSeq-class.html#select) function, but it is currently buggy as mentioned in this [bug report](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/30). Suggested workaround to get edge IDs of vertex X is to use `g.es[g.incident(x)]`.

Comment: The `from`, `to`, and `adj` iterators behave the same for non-directional graphs, but for directional graphs, the `adj` iterator is required to get all links attached to a vertex.  For directional graphs, `from` returns only edges that start at the supplied vertex; `to` returns only edges that end at the supplied vertex.  For both directional and non-directional graphs, `adj` will return all edges associated with the vertex.

Answer (score 7):

If you do not know the index of the vertex, you can find it using match() before using the from() function.

```
idx <- match("a", V(g)$name)
E(g) [ from(idx) ]
```

Comment: Simpler yet: `E(g) [ to("a") ]`

Answer (score 6):

Found a simpler version combining the two efforts above that may be useful too.

```
E(g)[from(V(g)["name"])]
```

Comment: This gave me an index, but not the actual name as in tuple of (Source_Node -> Destination_Node) (I am using directed graphs)

Comment: I would need more to help with what you're seeing. I seem to be able to pull out the to/from nodes.                                 
 require(igraph)
g1 <- graph( edges=c(1,2, 2,3, 3, 1), n=3, directed=T ) 
plot(g1)
E(g1)[from(V(g1)[2])]
> E(g1)[to(V(g1)[2])]
+ 1/3 edge from 74d9064:
  [1] 1->2
> E(g1)[from(V(g1)[2])]
+ 1/3 edge from 74d9064:
  [1] 2->3

Comment: Thank you, will try when I have more time today or the next days.

Answer (score 2):

I use this function for getting number of edges for all nodes:

```
sapply(V(g)$name, function(x) length(E(g)[from(V(g)[x])]))
```

Comment: When you can use `degree(g)` instead, you should.